# Hibernate Criteria: How to combine LEFT_OUTER_JOIN and RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN to perform FULL_JOIN

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to perform a FULL_JOIN by combining a LEFT_OUTER_JOIN and a RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN. I can use FULL_JOIN for MSSQL but not for MySQL as FULL_JOIN is not supported in MySQL. So, to perform a FULL_JOIN in MySQL, I have to combine a LEFT_OUTER_JOIN and RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN.

I have something as so

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class,
            "user");
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

Criteria userCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("user");
userCriteria .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List user1 = userCriteria.createAlias("userList",
                        "user1", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
                        .list();

List user2 = userCriteria.createAlias("userList",
                        "user2", JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN)
                        .list();

user1.addAll(user2);
```

but this gives me the error of

> Caught unknown exception of class org.hibernate.QueryException - duplicate association path: userList

How do I combine both JOINs into one using the same alias ?

P.S: I am an absolute beginner in Hibernate Criteria Query, any help or any references would be much appreciated

Comment: paste full code. What is userCriteria?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Updated the question @PeterŠály